# Remove affiliate links in questions or answers

Tags: discussion

The user in [this post](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/what-are-some-good-dog-toys-for-solo-play-in-an-apartment) linked to some toys that he uses, but he used an Amazon [affiliate link](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/1397/affiliate-link).

According to [this meta from 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/affiliate-links-amazon-and-others/2727#2727) we should either flag them as spam or edit them out. The question is otherwise good, so I edited them out.

Additionally, StackExchange [automatically changes Amazon links to their own affiliate link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links), so allowing obfuscated affiliate links in questions/answers prevents that revenue generating behavior for our hosts.

I'm posting here for awareness. Apparently this issue was raised a few months ago but no action was taken at the time.

Comment: Thank you, for this

Comment: @James I'm not really sure on this but I think amzn.to links are changed to the SE affiliate links as well, and from what I can see it seems to have happened here because the affiliate code seems the same before and after. So I'm wondering if maybe the OP didn't really include an affiliate link at all, perhaps you could use your mod super-powers to ping an SE employee to provide a definitive answer?

Comment: @PeterJ you might be over estimating mod super-powers.  You would probably have more luck posting a followup question https://meta.stackexchange.com linking to the existing question there.

Comment: @PeterJ the original links included the referrer tag 'vacatripbook-20' and the new links include the referrer tag 'stackoverfl08-20'

Comment: @Zaralynda ahh yes you're right - I was looking at the wrong section of the URL and thought SE must have been changing shortened links as well.